# Concatenating @if conditionals inside a href= attribute

Tags: laravel

I have the following `<li>` on my blade view, and i want to set a sequence of `@if @endif`, how to to this?

I'm trying to check if these variables are set or not, to include or not in the href.

The following  example is resulting in "spaces" between @ifs. how can I 'concatenate' them?

```
<li><a href="?status={{$status}}@if(!empty($order))&order={{$order}}@endif @if(!empty($query))&q={{$query}}@endif">{{$pages}}</a></li>
```

Ty in advance

Comment: It's probably better if you send the prepared string to your view. Might help to show what your controller looks like

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
<li><a href="?status={{$status}}{{!empty($order) ? '&order=' . $order : '' }}{{!empty($query) ? '&q=' . $query : ''}}">{{$pages}}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for better understanding, better logical control and clear solution.

```
@php 
$params = [
      'status' => $status;
];
if(!empty($order)){
     $params['order'] = $order;
}
if(!empty($query)){
     $params['query'] = $query;
}
$url = http_build_query($params);
@endphp
<li><a href="{{$url}}">{{$pages}}</a></li>
```

Comment: Isn't it to much logic delegated to the view ?

Comment: I wrote code in view for simple solution because we must focus how `http_build_query` simplifies things. He can produce url in controller or wherever if you want. In controller, helper, macro, view etc...

Comment: Sounds fair enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best practice IMO (maybe not THE best for all developers, but I often use it) is to handle this with a service.

You create a new provider (don't forget to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;` ) and paste this in the boot method

```php
    View::composer(['path.to.your.view'], function($view) {
    //You'll be surprised of what you get here
        dd($view->getData());
    });
```

EDIT : Can be changed according to Enver's answer

```php
    View::composer(['path.to.your.view'], function($view) {
        $params = [
          'status' => $view->getData()['status'];
        ];

    //and so on
    // then
    $view->(['url' => $url]);
    });
```

Then in your view

```
<li><a href="{{$url}}">{{$pages}}</a></li>
```